# Unorderedmap: Error in template arguments

Tags: c++, unordered

I am making an unordered map:
whose key consists of three characters
and value is integer.

Here is the code:

```
namespace G {

typedef std::tuple< char, char, char> key_t;

struct key_hash : public std::unary_function<key_t, std::size_t>
{
std::size_t operator()(const key_t& k) const
{
return std::get<0>(k) ^ std::get<1>(k) ^  std::get<2>(k);
}
};

struct key_equal : public std::binary_function<key_t, key_t, key_t,   bool>
{
bool operator()(const key_t& v0, const key_t& v1, const key_t& v2) const
{
return (
std::get<0>(v0) == std::get<0>(v1)  &&
std::get<1>(v0) == std::get<1>(v1) &&
std::get<2>(v0) == std::get<2>(v1) 

);
}
};

struct IndexGuide
{
int index;

};

typedef std::unordered_map<const key_t,IndexGuide,key_hash,key_equal> GuideDouble;
}
```

but when I compile the code, I get this error

```
In file included from StateTableGenerator.cpp:3:0:
StateTables.h:72:75: error: wrong number of template arguments (5, should be 3)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:115:12: error: provided for ‘template<class _Arg1, class _Arg2, class _Result> struct std::binary_function’
```

Plese help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you even read the error? It says you're passing the wrong number of template arguments for `std::binary_function`. And guess what, you *are.*

Comment: Side note: your hash could be improved. On most architectures, `sizeof(size_t) > 3`, which means simply shifting an OR-ing the chars would give a unique hash value for each key, making the hash function perfect (no collisions). And you don't really need `key_equal`, `std::tuple` provides `operator ==` which does exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: If this is all there is to it, you also don't need `key_hash` (at least not as-written). there is nothing stopping you from just specializing `std::hash<G::key_t>` and letting the standard lib take it from there.

Comment: @WhozCraig: "There is nothing stopping you..." - apart from `key_t` being an alias for a standard library type. You're only allowed to add specialisations to namespace `std` if they depend on user-defined types.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I wasn't aware that `G::key_t` was an alias to a standard type. My bad. You're correct. Were it his own struct it would be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is with your `key_equal`, where you make a *binary* function taking three arguments. A binary function is a function that takes two arguments.